# Cancel Parse Request If It Takes Too Long

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there a way to cancel a Parse request if someone has a very poor connection. Is there some sort of Parse method to do it? If not is there a way to time it out with a NSTimer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they haven't implemented that (according to their docs).  Making a request is kind of like releasing a balloon into the sky.  If the server gets the request, it'll respond to it, but there's no way to cancel the request mid-flight.  An interesting and related problem is the [2 Generals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem)